# Cannot read property 'getPicture' of undefined - ionic camera

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, yeoman, ionic-framework

this code returns:

```
 Cannot read property 'getPicture' of undefined
```

Have no idea what im doing wrong, can you please help me with the code?

My App:

> angular.module('Todo', ['ionic', 'Todo.controllers','ngStorage',
>   'Todo.services', 'ngCordova'])

my Controller:

```
.controller('profileEditCtrl', function($scope,Camera, $localStorage,
 $cordovaCamera) 
     {  
        $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({ data:[]});

    $scope.takePicture = function() 
    {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL }); 

      function onSuccess(imageData) {
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        image.src ="data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;       
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }       

}});
```

Comment: did you install this plugin? aka `cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git` and after android update?

Comment: BTW, there is no dependancy to Ionic.

Comment: i installed that plugin

Comment: can we please talk in chat? its kinda like a broken phone here...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25926840/237209

Comment: If you are testing your ionic app on browser, please try that on device. On browser, the Camera is indeed undefined.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Your code is correct, just add an html button with `ng-click="takePicture()"`.
- There is no problem here, It's sure that **the browser** `"cannot read
  property 'getPicture' of undefined"` because it has no configuration
  for a mobile camera that you defined, which means **you should test your application on
  a real device** using:

  `> ionic run android`.
- Notice that the new update of Google Chrome has a new feature which
  helps your test your device on the browser if it is connected to the
  PC/laptop, for testing go to chrome's navigation panel >> More tools >> Inspect devices
  or just go to this link:

  ***chrome://inspect/#devices***
- I'm sure your camera will function normally if you have the plugin cordova `plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera` installed in the app,
  I hope this helps you.

Comment: Have you tried this is it really working, in my case its not working

Comment: your suggest is all right. I did test on `chrome://inspect/#devices` and works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

After trying various solutions with no luck for my cordova project, I simply went ahead to use the [built-in JavaScript APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia). Essentially:

```
async function startCapturing() {   // get ready to shoot
    await getPermission('android.permission.CAMERA');
    let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: {width: 480, height: 320, facingMode:'environment' }, audio: false });
    let video = document.getElementById("pVideo");   // a <video> element
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.play();
    video.style.display = "block";
}

function shootPhoto(){       // take a snapshot
    let video = document.getElementById("pVideo");
    let canvas = document.getElementById("pCanvas");  // a <canvas> element
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(video,0,0,480,320);
    document.getElementById('fsPhotoI').src = Photo.current.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    Photo.current.changed = Profile.current.changed = true;
    video.style.display = "none";
}
```

In particular, some plugins did not work for me because they could't use the Android rear camera right away. The following in getUserMedia(...) does the trick:

```
facingMode:'environment'
```

Also make sure you have the CAMERA permission in your AndroidManifest.xml.