# $cordovaBLE not defined when using ngCordova in an Ionic/Angular project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have an AngularJS/Ionic app built on top of Phonegap. I am trying to use ngCordova with the cordova-plugin-ble-central plugin ($cordovaBLE in ngCordova). No matter what I try, $cordovaBLE is undefined. The call is in a service which is called in an event handler for a button.

My index.html includes are

```
<script src="js/thirdparty/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/thirdparty/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

My app injection is

```
angular.module('myapp', [
    'ionic',
    'ngCordova',
    'myapp.controller',
    'myapp.service'
]);
```

My controller definition is

```
angular.module('myapp.controller')

.controller('settingsCtrl', ['commServ', function (commServ) {
    var controller = this;

     // Bluetooth ------------
    controller.scan = function () {
        commServ.getDevices()
    };
}])
```

And my service definition is (myapp.service is defined elsewhere)

```
angular.module('myapp.service')

.factory('commServ', [function ($cordovaBLE) {
    // Get bluetooth devices
    service.getDevices = function () {
        console.log($cordovaBLE);

        return { error: null, success: true, value: [{ name: "Steve's Device" }] };
    };
}
```

The output in the console is always "undefined".

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25243905/469777

Comment: @StaffordWilliams - Unfortunately I've already looked at that post but it doesn't help. I'm testing directly on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have installed the plugin:

```
cordova plugin add com.megster.cordova.ble
```

I've noticed a few things in your code.

When you create a new module, as you're doing with `myapp.service` and `myapp.controller`, you have to use this format:

```
angular.module('myapp.service', [])
```

*notice the square brackets after the service module name.*

Your controller's module is called `awire.controller` but you inject it in the main module like `myapp.controller`.

There's another problems with your service.
When you register a service you always have to return it as in the [documents](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

You are returning an object

```
return { error: null, success: true, value: [{ name: "Steve's Device" }] };
```

but you're not instantiating the service:

> The service factory function generates the single object or function
>   that represents the service to the rest of the application. The object
>   or function returned by the service is injected into any component
>   (controller, service, filter or directive) that specifies a dependency
>   on the service.

I use this pattern from john papa's [style guides](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#factories) and your service would look like this:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myapp.service', [])
        .factory('commServ', commServ);

    commServ.$inject = ['$cordovaBLE'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function commServ($cordovaBLE) {

        console.log("factory => commServ => CREATE");

        var service = {
            getDevices: getDevices
        };

        return (service);

        function getDevices() {
            console.log($cordovaBLE);
            return {
                error: null,
                success: true,
                value: [{
                    name: "Steve's Device"
                }]
            };
        }
    }

})();
```

I've tested it on my android device and it works properly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback LeftyX. I have added the plugin. The module creation line you gave actually does exist, it's just in a different file. The notation I used is how you add a service in a separate file after the module has been created. The 'awire' reference was a typo and has been fixed. I've actually found the issue but hadn't had a chance to post the solution yet. The problem was I'd forgotten to add the '$cordovaBLE' injection string. I'll mark yours as the solution since it has that in there although this code style seems excessively complicated to me.

Comment: Solution was to add the $cordovaBLE injection in the service definition like:

    .factory('commServ', ['$cordovaBLE', function ($cordovaBLE) {

Comment: Glad I've helped, in a way. The style comes from John Papa. It seems complicated at the beginning but it helps you a lot when you have modules with a great number of lines.